# Print the correct Morse code for alpha entry

Tags: c

I now need to output the Morse code equivalent of alphanumeric input.  My condition for check this is an if loop:  I try to look at each element of input array with each element of the alpha array but a match never seems to be found.  I am not sure if I am using the correct method.  I try to de-reference the point to input and compare the value with each element of alpha until a match is found.  If no match is found then an error occurs.

Not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{

char *morse[] = {"/",
    ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--","....","..",".---",
    "-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-",
    "..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",
    "-----",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----."};
char *alpha[]= {" ",
    "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
    "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
    "U","V","W","X","Y", "Z",
    "0", "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};


 char *print_array[50];
 int print_array_index = 0;

 char hold[50];
 int hold_index = 0;

 char input[200];
 int i = 0;

 printf("welcome to the Morse translator.\n");
 printf("Enter input: ");
 fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

char *p;
for (p=input; *p !='\0';++p)
{
    *p = toupper(*p);
}

 if (input[0]=='-' || input[0]=='.')
 {


    while (input[i] !='\0') {

        if (input[i] ==' ' || input[i] == '\n')
        {
            hold[hold_index] = '\0';

            bool found = false;

            for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(morse) / sizeof(char *); x++)
            {
                if (strcmp(morse[x], hold) == 0)
                {
                    print_array[print_array_index++] = alpha[x];

                    found = true;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid Morse code!\n");
            }

            hold_index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            hold[hold_index++] = input[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < print_array_index; x++)
    {
        printf("%s", print_array[x]);

    }

    printf("\n");
}
else if (isalnum(input[0]))
{
    while (input[i]!='\0')
    {
        if (input[i] ==' ' || input[i] == '\n')
        {
            bool found = false;
        for (int x=0; x < sizeof(alpha)/sizeof  (char*);x++)
            {
                if (alpha[x]==input[i])
                {
        print_array    [print_array_index++] = alpha[x];
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n");
            }
            hold_index = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (int x=0; x < print_array_index; x++)
    {
        printf("%s",print_array[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
        }           
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

part of `else if (isalnum(input[0])){` should be something like

```
else if (isalnum(input[0])){
    while (input[i]!='\0' && input[i]!='\n'){
        bool found = false;
        for (int x=0; x < sizeof(alpha)/sizeof(char*);x++){
            if (*alpha[x]==input[i]){
                print_array[print_array_index++] = morse[x];
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n");
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (int x=0; x < print_array_index; x++){
        printf("%s", print_array[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I am beginning to understand how pointers work

Comment: @Brett One of the main problems is `if (input[i] ==' ' || input[i] == '\n')` : Not accepted most of the characters. 2) `if (alpha[x]==input[i])` :  Since `alpha[x]` is a string(`char*`) can not be judged as it is an equal value. It must be a character. 3) `print_array[print_array_index++] = alpha[x];` :  `alpha[x]` should be `morse[x]`